# Django / SQLite : Is there a way to see if someone is *currently* logged-in by checking db.sqlite3?

Tags: django, sqlite

I'm using Django 1.10 with SQLite as my database back-end.
I have a site running with nginx/uwsgi and the above configuration, which I'm constantly updating with new code.

Each time I want to update the site code, I'm shutting down uwsgi, nginx, `git pull` ing the new version from my repo, then restarting uwsgi and nginx.

While this works, in the sense that the site is updated with the new version of my code, the side-effect is that in the event that a user is currently logged in the site and working on something (which generally will result in modifying the db), the user's work will be interrupted.

Worse still would be the case that the new version of my code contains migrations, which will change the db structure, with (unpredictable?) consequences on the user's on-going work.

So the question is: is there a way, like a command-line script, to check `db.sqlite3` and see if a user is currently logged-in, before deciding to shutdown uwsgi and nginx ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say **NO**. There is chances like

- User logged in and didn't log out for a while.
- Logged in, but inactive

We can get logged in users who didnt logout in `django_session` table.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to minimize the downtime. As a start, there's no reason to restart nginx when you update your code or uwsgi, and you can `git pull` without affecting the currently running code, so you don't need to stop uwsgi before pulling in the new code.

When it comes to migrations, try to avoid any migrations that will break the currently running code. For example, don't delete fields/models that are still used by the current code, but wait until the next update (when those fields/models are no longer in use). That way you can run your migrations while you're still running the old code, without generating any errors.

Next up, you should [reload](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#reloading-the-server) the uwsgi process rather than stopping and starting it manually. This will finish handling any open requests before reloading the process. It will also keep on listening for new requests, so that these can be handled immediately after the process has reloaded. Users may experience a slowdown, but this will not drop any requests unless the queue fills up before the process can be reloaded. For small-scale websites this should never happen.

So, to avoid downtime you can use this to update your website:

```
$ git pull                   # pull in new code while the old process is still running
$ python manage.py migrate   # run your migrations, and possibly `collectstatic` etc.
$ kill -HUP `cat <pidfile>`  # gracefully reload the uwsgi process
```